# Unable to update outputText when a fileUpload happens

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces 6 and want to write a form with a number of file upload fields. This is gonna be dynamic: Sometimes there will be 6 fields, sometimes just 2, sometimes 29 (!).

After every fileUpload, I have an outputText to show the name of the uploaded file, if it's already uploaded. When a file upload happens, my messages and growl components are successfully updated, but not the outputText field (exactly the field with the dynamic id). How can I fix this? I already tried updating the outputText field, the mother h:panelGroup and the p:panelGrid. I think my dynamic id solution is not going to work.

```
 <c:forEach items="#{myBean.myList}" var="tipoArq" varStatus="varStatus">
    <p:panelGrid id="#{'panelGroupArquivo'.concat(tipoArq.ordem)}">
        <div style="overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <p:fileUpload id="#{'arquivo'.concat(tipoArq.ordem)}"
                fileUploadListener="#{myBean.uploadSomeFile}"
                mode="advanced" 
                update="#{'nomeArquivo'.concat(tipoArq.ordem)} messages :form:growl" 
                auto="true"
                sizeLimit="#{tipoArq.tipoArqAnual.maxSize}" 
                allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/"
                style="width: 500px;" required="true">
                <f:attribute name="idTipoArquivoAnualTipoUg" value="#{tipoArq.id}" />
            </p:fileUpload>
        </div>
        <h:outputText id="#{'nomeArquivo'.concat(tipoArq.ordem)}"                                    
             value="#{myBean.getFileNameByOrdem(tipoArq.ordem)}" style="margin-right: 5px;"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
    <br/>
</c:forEach>
```

I tried using the following syntaxes in the update property:

- ## {'nomeArquivo'.concat(tipoArq.ordem)}
- ## {':form:nomeArquivo'.concat(tipoArq.ordem)}
- ## {'form:nomeArquivo'.concat(tipoArq.ordem)}
- ## {'panelGroupArquivo'.concat(tipoArq.ordem)}
- ## {':form:panelGroupArquivo'.concat(tipoArq.ordem)}
- ## {nomeArquivo.concat(tipoArq.ordem)} (as recommended in comments)

This panelGrid was originally a h:panelGroup, tried to update it with no success.
Is there other way I can indicate to the p:fileUpload that I want it to update the outputText field right next to him?

Thanks in advance, sorry about my broken english. =]

Comment: if you comment that output text, is there any other error? is this line working `<p:fileUpload id="#{'arquivo'.concat(tipoArq.ordem)}"`?

Comment: is `nomeArquivo` a variable? Try `#{nomeArquivo.concat(tipoArq.ordem)}`

Comment: Hi @TomBrito, sorry for delaying it so much. If I take off the "update", all works fine. IE: update="messages :form:growl" works fine, but when I add the dynamic id it says the component can't be found.

Comment: `nomeArquivo` is the prefix every outputText id have... I tried using `update="#{nomeArquivo.concat(tipoArq.ordem)} messages :form:growl"`, the page opens, it updates the `:form:growl` when a file upload happens, but the `outputText` isn't updated. I think it is not found using that syntax.

Comment: Look at what the client-side ID actually is (hint: you cannot set dynamic id's this way! Only in c:foreach loops)

Comment: I didn't knew it, thanks! I'll try the `c:forEach` right now.

Comment: @Kukeltje I changed to c:forEach, so on client-side the outputText is shown as a span with id `form:nomeArquivo1`. I tried using `#{'form:nomeArquivo'.concat(tipoArq.ordem)}`, `#{':form:nomeArquivo'.concat(tipoArq.ordem)}` and `#{'nomeArquivo'.concat(tipoArq.ordem)}` in fileUpload's update, still with no sucess. I'll update my question to reflect these changes.

Comment: what did you further debug?Tried developement mode? Checked the requests/responses? Error log? Added a messages component? If an update cannot be found there most often is an explicit error

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje, you solved the problem!

Wildfly error log was clean, messages component was working fine. So I checked the response. A post with status 200. It was a xml with 3 *update* tags. The other tags with the correct message written, and the *update* with a span and the desired id was empty. 

The problem was: the *value* of the outputText was wrong. The method didn't return any string, so the span was updated with an empty value. I was failing in my bean logic, that method, not in the xhtml file.

Thanks guys! =]

Comment: Therefor ALWAYS create a [mcve], ALWAYS... it helps you narrow down the problem before posting and it very often helps you solve it yourself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem was that the value of my outputText was empty. I discovered it by debugging the requests of the page: After a fileUpload there was a response, in XML format, with other message components containing the correct text, and the span field (outputText) was there too, but empty.